# How to output a spectrum Fast Fourier Transform on C++

Tags: c++, fft, dft, spectrum

I'm using [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch11s18.html) code to compute the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) efficiently using the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) algorithm, I'm new to this topic and I don't really understand what do I need to do after getting the output from the fft which are basically 8 points that are describing each wave.

My end goal is to show a spectrum according to the sample points I wrote

Again, I'm no expert and I can really use example or articles because all that data I found online doesn't tell me what do I do with these points to compute the spectrum.

FFT code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

unsigned int bitReverse(unsigned int x, int log2n) {
    int n = 0;
    int mask = 0x1;
    for (int i = 0; i < log2n; i++) {
        n <<= 1;
        n |= (x & 1);
        x >>= 1;
    }
    return n;
}

const double PI = 3.1415926536;

template<class Iter_T>
void fft(Iter_T a, Iter_T b, int log2n)
{
    typedef typename iterator_traits<Iter_T>::value_type complex;
    const complex J(0, 1);
    int n = 1 << log2n;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        b[bitReverse(i, log2n)] = a[i];
    }
    for (int s = 1; s <= log2n; ++s) {
        int m = 1 << s;
        int m2 = m >> 1;
        complex w(1, 0);
        complex wm = exp(-J * (PI / m2));
        for (int j = 0; j < m2; ++j) {
            for (int k = j; k < n; k += m) {
                complex t = w * b[k + m2];
                complex u = b[k];
                b[k] = u + t;
                b[k + m2] = u - t;
            }
            w *= wm;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    typedef complex<double> cx;
    cx a[] = { cx(1,0), cx(3,0), cx(5,0), cx(7,0),
      cx(9, 0), cx(11, 0), cx(13,0), cx(15,0) };
    cx b[8];
    fft(a, b, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        cout << b[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "show a spectrum"?

Comment: Are you asking how to render the spectrum? You'd use a graphics library, for example, Qt.

Comment: So after getting the points, what steps do I need to do before actually rendering the image? (how do I know the frequency, time, intensity) from those 8 points the fft computed me @Scheff

Comment: So your question is about the meaning of the output of the DFT, and not related to programming? Then try https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ instead. But do note that this question has very likely been answered before there, so please search before posting your question.

Comment: it's both because I don't know how to render spectrum as well @CrisLuengo

Comment: Then you have two different questions. First figure out what you need to plot, then figure out how to plot it. When you ask how to plot your data, make sure you know what graphics framework you want to use, because recommendations for those are out of scope for Stack Overflow. See [ask].